# Store an object in Zend Registry

Tags: php, zend-framework, registry

How do you store an object in a Zend_Registry instance so that each property of the object is loaded as the index and each value of the object's property is stored as the registry's value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered my own question.  Create a class extending Zend_Registry and add the following method:

```
public static function loadObject($object){
    $data = get_object_vars($object);
    foreach($data as $key => $value){
        self::set($key, $value);
    }
}
```

Comment: well that was fast u asked and answerd on you own .

Comment: Hopefully other people can use this method.

Comment: This is great as long as all you need loaded is public properties. Wouldn't it be better just to implement toArray() in your object and then dump the array into the registry. You could do it as a whole array or iterate over the array and add the keys as indexes.

Comment: you could do foreach($object as $key => $value), but again that would only return the public properties